# zsh: invalid base (must be 2 to 36 inclusive): 64

Tags: math, zsh

`echo $((64#23GDW0))`

This works fine in `bash`, for instance, displaying "2208988800", as expected, but fails and produces the following error message when run in `zsh`:

`zsh: invalid base (must be 2 to 36 inclusive): 64`

is there a way to make this run in `zsh` ?

Comment: Search for `zsh base64`; it seems some coding required unfortunately. Base64 uses alpanumeric ASCII (10+26+26) plus two extra chars, `/` and `+`.

Answer (score 1):

According to [zsh manual](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Arithmetic-Evaluation.html)

> Integers may also be of the form ‘base#n’, where `base` is a decimal number between **two** and **thirty-six** representing the arithmetic base and `n` is a number in that base (for example, ‘16#ff’ is 255 in hexadecimal).

Since there are no built-in support in zsh, you have to handle it on your own, either by tricky zsh functions or external programs.